# Is there a way to apply ReSharper code cleanup settings to .scss (SASS) files?

Tags: sass, formatting, resharper

We use ReSharper's *silent code cleanup* functionality to achieve a consistent code layout within our team. For `C#` and `JavaScript` code it works fine, but we'd also like to apply a common formatting style to `.scss` files (used by SASS). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper does not support [SASS](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-404300), so there is no way to apply ReSharper Code cleanup to `.sass` files

Comment: It's unfortunate. It would be fairly straightforward to add. Combination of CSS and Script.